# udefined audio.canPlayType in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, modernizr

i have some issue 
the problem is i used  audio.canPlayType in my code 
this is my code :

```
var audio = document.createElement( 'audio' );

        if ( audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;') ) {

            return 'mp3';

        }
        else if ( audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg;') ) {

            return 'ogg';

        }
        else {

            return 'wav';

        }
```

and evrything is fine except when i used in safari or browser in ios platforms
and when i checked with safari i got the

```
 if ( audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;') ) {
```

is equal to undefiend
i really appreciated if someone help me to solve this issue on ios browser in clude safari,chrome ...

Edit on 12-20-2015 12:48 : 
i found the problem was something else the issue came from this code

```
$.when( this.sound.play( 'click' ) ).done( function() {
```

the problem is come on all browser in iphone that can't detect this event :(
can someone help to me?

Comment: So it works in every other browser, just not Safari? Where does jQuery come into this, is the `audio` element created exactly as you've shown ?

Comment: it doesnt work on safari and all browser i tried in iphone (ios platform)

Comment: but work in all browser in windows,firefox,chrome...

Comment: this is my linke - > http://khanedecor.com/mplayer/

Comment: And the error is coming from the cassette.js plugin ?

Comment: yes the error com from jquery.cassette.js

Comment: ios is 9.2,and also all browser latest version , chrome , safari, firefox... all browser on ios

Comment: yes firefox came for ios recently,so is there a way to change event that ios can detect on click ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the semicolons ';'

```
var audio = document.createElement( 'audio' );

    if ( audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ) {

        return 'mp3';

    }
    else if ( audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ) {

        return 'ogg';

    }
    else {

        return 'wav';

    }
```

line 3 and 8.

Comment: jquery.cassette.js:20TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg')')

Comment: Be sure that your browser support the technology http://caniuse.com/#search=audio and if you can put the full code here.
if you don't buffer the file is ok that the script return this error

Comment: this is the plugin that i used -> http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/07/12/old-school-cassette-player-with-html5-audio/